# Foundation 4 Reveal and WP AJAX: Previous/Next Modal Window from Open Modal Window?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I'm building a custom gallery that utilizes WordPress and Zurb Foundation:

- The template shows a paged archive of custom posts; a custom query populates the page with a grid of linked thumbnails.
- Uses the Reveal modal plugin in Foundation 4, along with WordPress' AJAX to append content to the reveal-modal div.
- Clicking on a `.previous-sketch`, `.next-sketch` link in the modal window will bring up the corresponding adjacent post.

I've managed to get the above working, but find that after opening one modal window and cycling through the posts, things start to go out of sync. The dark background, `.reveal-modal-bg` is not displayed when a modal window is shown, and things behave somewhat strangely.

I thank you in advance if you have any particular insights into this problem.

UPDATE: I was able to work on this some more, and for the most part it seems to work. Though I feel that my solution isn't the most elegant.

My jQuery code is below.

```
(function($) {

 $.fn.displayPost = function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var post_id = $(this).data("id");
    var id = "#" + post_id;

    // Check if the reveal modal for the specific post id doesn't already exist by checking for it's length
    if($(id).length == 0 ) {
        // We'll add an ID to the new reveal modal; we'll use that same ID to check if it exists in the future.
        var modal = $('<div>').attr('id', post_id ).addClass('reveal-modal').appendTo('body');
        var ajaxURL = MyAjax.ajaxurl;
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxURL,
            data: {"action": "load-content", post_id: post_id },
            success: function(response) {
                modal.empty().html(response).append('<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>').foundation('reveal', 'open');

                modal.bind('opened', function() {
                    // Trigger window resize to reset the left margin.  
                    $(window).trigger('resize');
                    var left;
                    left = Math.max($(window).width() - $(id).outerWidth(), 0) / 2;
                    $(id).css({
                        left:left + $(window).scrollLeft()
                    });

                return false;
                });
            }
        });
    }
     //If the div with the ID already exists we'll just open it.
     else {
         $(id).foundation('reveal', 'open');
     }

     // Recalculate left margin on window resize
     $(window).resize(function(){
        var left;
        left = Math.max($(window).width() - $(id).outerWidth(), 0) / 2;
        $(id).css({
            left:left + $(window).scrollLeft()
        });
     });
}

})(jQuery);

// Apply the function when we click on the .reveal link
jQuery(document).on("click", ".reveal,.secondary", function() {
    jQuery(this).displayPost();
});

// Use Reveal's built in function to close the div when we click our paging links
jQuery(document).on("click", ".secondary", function() {
    var id = jQuery(this).closest("div").attr("id");
    jQuery(id).foundation('reveal', 'close');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure that someone here probably knows a much better way to do this, but for the sake of anyone else that is trying to figure this out, I managed to kludge a solution. It works, though I haven't tested it thoroughly.

The function extends Foundation 4 Reveal's functionality in a few ways:

- Uses WordPress AJAX to dynamically pull in content to populate a modal div.
- Centers the modal div and allows it to be variable width.
- Adds paging navigation from the modal window that when triggered will close the open modal window, then open the previous/next modal content.

Here's the code:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.displayPost = function() {

    event.preventDefault();

    var post_id = $(this).data("id");
    var id = "#" + post_id;

    // Check if the reveal modal for the specific post id doesn't already exist by checking for it's length
    if($(id).length == 0 ) {
        // We'll add an ID to the new reveal modal; we'll use that same ID to check if it exists in the future.
        var modal = $('<div>').attr('id', post_id ).addClass('reveal-modal').appendTo('body');
        var ajaxURL = MyAjax.ajaxurl;
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxURL,
            data: {"action": "load-content", post_id: post_id },
            success: function(response) {
                modal.empty().html(response).append('<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>').foundation('reveal', 'open');
                modal.bind('opened', function() {
                    // Reset visibility to hidden and set display: none on closed reveal-modal divs, for some reason not working by default when reveal close is triggered on .secondary links  
                    $(".reveal-modal:not('.reveal-modal.open')").css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'display' : 'none'})
                    // Trigger resize 
                    $(window).trigger('resize');
                return false;
                });
            }
        });
    }
     //If the div with the ID already exists just open it.
     else {
         $(id).foundation('reveal', 'open');
     }

     // Recalculate left margin on window resize to allow for absolute centering of variable width elements
     $(window).resize(function(){
         var left;
            left = Math.max($(window).width() - $(id).outerWidth(), 0) / 2;
            $(id).css({
                left:left + $(window).scrollLeft()
            });
     });
    }

     })(jQuery);

     // Apply the function when we click on the .reveal link
     // (document).ready won't work on any reveal-modal divs added subsequently
     // after page load via AJAX so use .on instead.
     jQuery(document).on("click", ".reveal,.secondary", function() {
      jQuery(this).displayPost();

     });

      // Close open modal via secondary paging links; target parent div id.
      jQuery(document).on("click", ".secondary", function() {
        var id = jQuery(this).closest("div").attr("id");
      jQuery(id).foundation('reveal', 'close');
      });
```

UPDATE: Added php function for loading AJAX content

```
  public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-content', array($this, 'load_ajax_content' ));
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-content', array($this, 'load_ajax_content' ));
    }



        /**
         * Function to call the content loaded for logged-in and anonymous users
        */
        public function load_ajax_content ( $post_id ) {

            $post_id = $_POST[ 'post_id' ];

            if (has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {
                $sketch_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);  
                $attachment = get_post( $sketch_id );
                $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
                $response = '<figure>'. get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large-sketch') .'<figcaption><p>'. $caption .'</p></figcaption></figure>' . $this->paging_link_nav( $post_id );
                echo $response;
            }

            die(1);
         }
```

Hopefully someone else finds this useful...

Comment: This is very cool, but I feel like I'm missing something because the container that is created has no id set, and therefore no modal is shown. This is how I am creating the link that is trying to fire the modal: `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', '_sf' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" data-reveal-id="<?php the_id(); ?>" data-reveal-ajax="true" "rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>`. I'm pretty sure setting `data-reveal-id` to be the post ID is what I'm supposed to do. Is that not right or am I missing something else?

Comment: In my experience I found that using Reveal's inbuilt AJAX call was actually not workable with WP's native AJAX. To fire the modal I used the following `<a href="<?php echo $large_image; ?>" data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"  class="reveal" >
                      <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'medium-sketch'); ?>`  I just used a generic `data-id`

Comment: Just to further elaborate `var post_id = $(this).data("id");` is looking for `data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"`.

Comment: First off, thanks for your help. Much closer now. First, I realized that I needed to localize  the script to set the ajax-url. I did that plus change the data attribute as you suggested. Now I get the modal, but no content:(. Also its half off of the left side of the window in Chrome. In Firefox, it just loads the post's page as if none of this is happening, which is very polite of it.

Comment: I think that you're on the right track. I updated my code above with and example of my plugin function that loads the AJAX content for the modal. In the function `$this->paging_link_nav( $post_id )` refers to a custom paging link function; using [next/previous post link plus plugin](http://www.ambrosite.com/plugins/next-previous-post-link-plus-for-wordpress) to create the modal's previous and next links. Not ideal, because it's relying on a plugin, but it was an easy way to add navigation. As far as the centering goes, it may be because there's no content in the div.

Comment: More progrees made, and more thanks to you.   I created a function to define `$response` as `get_the_title($post_id);` which actually cauced this to return the title. But it still has that zero next to it and the modal is half off-screen. What I can't figure out is what is caucing that zero? My functions for this, if anyone is intrested can be seen at: https://github.com/Shelob9/_sf_lib/blob/1.1-modal-posts/post-reveal.php